# Josephson supercurrent measurement in a lab

Tags: superconductivity, quantum-optics, quantum-computer, quantum-measurements, josephson-junction

This may be a very trivial question but I am a theoretician and can't find the answer to this question for the life of me. Is it possible to actually measure the Josephson supercurrent flowing through a Josephson junction in a lab? Specifically, can we actually get data that can help us plot the current value as it changes with time (or Fourier transform of it)?
Can we see the supercurrent $$I(t) = I_c \sin{\phi(t)}$$ in the lab? $I_c$ is the critical current.
Any references are much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You are not only interested in the frequency, but also in the exact amplitude of the current, is that right?

Comment: @sir_khorneflakes, Yes, the amplitude as well. In reality, I am interested in time-domain current (time-resolved current). That will automatically give me the amplitudes of Fourier components.

Comment: It is straightforward to measure the b field, you may find benefit searching with that mind

Comment: @KFGauss You are right. I think a DC-SQUID device should be able to do that. However, can you still suggest some reference(s)?